# How can I wait for text to be visible then click on button in Karate (Android)

Tags: android, karate

Thanks to Peter for such a wonderful karate framework. Was able to achieve a lot in quite some time for API

Recently started automation of IOS and Android app test, but need a help

How can I wait for a text to appear and click on Skip button in my Android test

I tried below code , but I am sure I am not doing it correct

```
 * driver.waitForText('body', 'How it works') - This line not working
 * driver.click("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Skip']")  - This line works
```

[image: App image]

I would like to wait until a text appears and then click on skip button

Comment: I've asked around since this is not my area of expertise, hopefully someone responds soon. but it would be good if you can go deep and help improve the framework + contribute code. I do feel that `body` is specific to HTML and you need to find a selector for mobile, maybe you can try `*`

Answer (score 1):

Right now all `waitFor` APIs are only supported for Web UI (both desktop and mobile browsers). Looking at you question this seems important for mobile as well, will see if we can make this available on next release.

```
* def headerText = driver.text('<locator>')
```

should give you the **text** of the element and can be leveraged for assertion or JS function to poll this element until you get the expected value

Comment: Hi Babu and Peter , many thanks for your answers . I tried with * , but as expected it did not work. I will wait for next release to test * def headerText = driver.text('<locator>')