# Karate : Android /IOS scroll down to element and input with delay's not working as expected

Tags: android, ios, karate

Below is the code snipet :
Issue 1) Input not working with delay
delay(3000)
input("//*[@Class='android.widget.EditText']", 'Automation: Executive Briefing', 200)
delay(3000)
input(""//*[@Class='android.widget.EditText']", ['A', 'u', 't', Key.ENTER], 200)
delay(3000)
Issue is:
Expected: The expected outcome is to print " Automation: 'delay 200' Executive 'delay 200' Briefing
Actual: But it is writing input is way like 'A' clear's the text from input box , the again enters 'u', then again clear 'u' and then enter 't'

Issue 2) Scroll down to element in Android /IOS using Karate not working as expected

Used code:    * script("mobile: scroll", {direction: 'down'} )
And     * scroll("//*[contains(@class,'search-result-pagination')]/descendant::li[2]")
Both didnt work  As one has any solution.

Note: Tried using Javascript code to have things worked out as well.
Though somewhat similar set of actions using Karate Framework worked totally fine for Web-Based automation

Scroll down to element and input with delays should work properly using Android/IOS using Karate Framework.

Comment: mobile support in karate is experimental and needs code contribution. you can get some more information about the current state here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64875193/143475